# Whats a good UX solution for a user to cover for another user while they go on leave?

Tags: accounts, permissions

I'm currently designing a feature where supervisors monitor various reports. These reports need to be monitored daily. Each user is assigned access to specific groups of reports.

As with any company, users go on leave several times a year. During this time another user will need to cover for the user going on leave.

Currently, what happens is users give access to their colleagues covering for them by sharing their login details. This creates security risks.

I'm trying to design a user flow that would help them achieve this without sharing their login details. Some potential solutions

- Giving temporary permission to the user going on leave's account.
- give access to the specific reports for the covering user's account.

are there any better solutions for this? it seems like a common problem enough for there to be a good solution for this already.

Comment: What is the function of the user who is covering for the person going on leave? Are they a supervisor who needs temporary access to reports? Or are they a non-supervisor generating reports during the leave period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best practice research:** Jira and other issue trackers are very good examples for this problem. In Jira, you can assign people to issues, give them roles, rights etc. So it is easy to assign someone else if the previous person is not available anymore.

But, there are several questions I see here:

- It is an edge case? If so, how much effort is allowed to put into it?
- If it is not an edge case, can we use this task delegation feature in more use cases too? (Because if yes, you can turn this into something totally different at the end.)

I think, sharing accounts is not the right solution, but I can understand that it is an edge case right now, because this happens only few times a year. The most future-proof solution would be, if you implement an issue management system very similar to Jira. A simple one is when you add this feature to the profile itself. In the profile settings page, you just create a new option where the user can set its own profile as absent, and when this is active, the user have to select from a dropdown menu another user who will be responsible for the tasks during this period. From a technical perspective, it is just a "redirection of tasks", or a "temporary" change in ownership of tasks. All other personal info, messages will be not affected.